# Using titlepages with memoir

Tags: memoir, titling

I was wondering how to use the titlepage package together with the memoir package. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

The code is from \titleHGP on pages 48-49 of the titlepages.pdf

I'm looking for this
[image: I'm looking for this]

but I'm getting this instead.
[image: but I'm getting this instead.]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{titlepages}
\newcommand*{\titleHGP}{\begingroup% Handy Guide to Papermaking
\drop=0.1\txtheight
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.05\txtwidth}
\color{Red}
\rule{6pt}{\txtheight}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.05\txtwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\txtwidth}
\vspace*{\drop}
{\Large THE AUTHOR} \\
\rule{0.9\txtwidth}{1pt} \par
\vspace{3\baselineskip}
{\noindent\Huge\bfseries CONUNDRUMS} \par
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
{\Large\itshape A Handy Guide to Puzzles and Enigmas} \par
\vspace{6.5\baselineskip}
{\scshape after the foreign edition of year \\
translated by} \par
\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}
{\Large THE TRANSLATOR} \par
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\rule{0.9\txtwidth}{1pt} \par
\vspace{\baselineskip}
{\Large THE PUBLISHER}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\txtwidth}
{\color{Red}
\FSfont{5fh}% FontSite Fette Gotisch
\HUGE
\vspace{3.3\baselineskip}
H \\[1.15\baselineskip]
G \\[1.15\baselineskip]
P \\[1.15\baselineskip]
E
}\par
\vspace{4\baselineskip}
{\Large YEAR}
\end{minipage}
\endgroup}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\titleHGP
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You aren't saying what problem you have and what you expect. Can you please either show an error message, or an image of the result with an explanation of what you wanted?

Comment: I edited the question with my expectations.

Comment: It might be a silly question, but are you sure that package `titlepages` exists? Here with a full TeX Live 2022, this package is unknown, and all I find on CTAN is a document with that name, but it isn't a package, it's a compilation of good-looking title pages.

Comment: I wouldn't use the `titlepages` package at all, but just copy that code you have inside `\titleHGP` into the `titlingpage` env directly in your memoir document. Feel free to copy the designed in `titlepages`.

Comment: @Daleif I get the exact same output when I remove the titlepages package and just use the code for the \titleHGP command. Two pages, one empty, then the screenshot from above.

Comment: @Jan oh no you don't because the code does not compile. Don't ignore compilation errors.

Comment: @daleif It does compile and looks the same as with the original code, I used `\begin{titlingpage}` and within that `\newcommand` and then `\titleHGP`

Comment: @Jan it surely does not compile, (1) you need to have copied `titlepages.sty` as it is not in LaTeX by default. Secondly it uses stuff from `memsty.sty` which you don't load. I'd like to see the log from the compilation. Just because you get a pdf is not that same as it compiled without errors. The fact that your image says  `=0.1Red` at the top is also an indicator of compilation errors. Additionally the color `Red` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Ahh, just realised where you're ccoming from. But there is no package called `titlepage` where do you have that from?

Comment: @Miyase as you say there is no package called `titlepage`. The code comes from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/latex-samples/TitlePages but the sample it self is not enough, it needs code from the source of that info document

Comment: @daleif Ah, I see, I already have the `memsty.sty` and `titlepages.sty`, probably from the `memoir` package. `titlepage` I got from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlepages?lang=en)

Comment: @Jan those are not related, you need code from the sources of the PDF you copied from. I think I can get most to work (except the gothic letters as that is a commercial font).

Comment: @daleif I don't even need _that_ titlepage in particular, just trying to get any of the templates to work - they're all quite beautiful.  Point being that I don't feel I have the knowledge to design my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`titlepages`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlepages?lang=en) on CTAN is not a package; it's just a showcase of what other people have done.

It provides the code used by other people. Unfortunately it takes that code somewhat out of context, and does not tell you what packages, page geometry, etc., the people who originally created the titlepage used. You're more or less left to figure those things out yourself.

To reproduce that particular sample, I had to define some additional lengths, scaling them to the fact that memoir with a4 uses bigger pages, and I had to download the font [ds-fette-gotisch.ttf from here](https://www.1001fonts.com/ds-fette-gotisch-font.html). Since that's a truetype font, to use it, I had to load the fontspec package, which means you'll have to compile this code with xelatex rather than pdflatex. But you could modify it to use some other blackletter font instead. For options, see the [LaTeX font catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/blackletterfonts.html).

I made some other small modifications in the attempt to match the original.

```
%xelatex 
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newlength{\drop}
\newlength{\txtwidth}
\setlength{\txtwidth}{0.95\textwidth}
\newlength{\txtheight}
\setlength{\txtheight}{0.95\textheight}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand{\FSfont}[1]{\fontspec[Extension=.ttf,Scale=1.6]{ds-fette-gotisch.regular}}
\newcommand*{\titleHGP}{\begingroup% Handy Guide to Papermaking
\drop=0.1\txtheight
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.05\txtwidth}
\color{Red}
\rule{6pt}{\txtheight}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.05\txtwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\txtwidth}
\vspace*{\drop}
{\Large THE AUTHOR} \\
\rule{0.9\txtwidth}{1pt} \par
\vspace{3\baselineskip}
{\noindent\Huge\bfseries CONUNDRUMS} \par
\vspace{2\baselineskip}\raggedright
{\Large\itshape A Handy Guide to Puzzles and Enigmas} \par
\vspace{6.5\baselineskip}
{\scshape\fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\selectfont after the foreign edition of year \\
translated by} \par
\vspace{0.2\baselineskip}
{\Large THE TRANSLATOR} \par
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\rule{0.9\txtwidth}{1pt} \par
\vspace{\baselineskip}
{\Large THE PUBLISHER}
\end{minipage}
%\hfill
\hspace{0.6in}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\txtwidth}
{\color{Red}
\FSfont{5fh}% FontSite Fette Gotisch
\HUGE
\vspace{3.9\baselineskip}
H \\[1.15\baselineskip]
G \\[1.15\baselineskip]
P \\[1.15\baselineskip]
E
}\par
\vspace{4\baselineskip}
{\Large YEAR}
\end{minipage}
\endgroup}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\titleHGP
\end{document}
```

[image: duplicating example from titlepages.pdf]

If there's another example you'd like to try to recreate, let us know.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm amazed at how helpful this community is.

Comment: How do I get more line spacing? The title is a bit longer and spans three lines, so it's all bunched up. I tried `\linespread{2}` but that doesn't work.

Comment: You can do that in a variety of ways like setting the `\baselinskip` length, but for a title you only need to do once, I'd probably just make the linebreaks manually with  `\\ `  and add a length afterwards `\\[1.0ex]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

titlepages is not a package but a sample document. If you want to use one of the titlepages it defines you must copy all the needed definitions from the document too. E.g.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand*{\FSfont}[1]{%
  \fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont}
\newlength{\tpheight}\setlength{\tpheight}{0.9\textheight}
\newlength{\txtheight}\setlength{\txtheight}{0.9\tpheight}
\newlength{\tpwidth}\setlength{\tpwidth}{0.9\textwidth}
\newlength{\txtwidth}\setlength{\txtwidth}{0.9\tpwidth}
\newlength{\drop}
\newcommand*{\titleHGP}{\begingroup% Handy Guide to Papermaking
\drop=0.1\txtheight
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.05\txtwidth}
\color{Red}
\rule{6pt}{\txtheight}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.05\txtwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\txtwidth}
\vspace*{\drop}
{\Large THE AUTHOR} \\
\rule{0.9\txtwidth}{1pt} \par
\vspace{3\baselineskip}
{\noindent\Huge\bfseries CONUNDRUMS} \par
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
{\Large\itshape A Handy Guide to Puzzles and Enigmas} \par
\vspace{6.5\baselineskip}
{\scshape after the foreign edition of year \\
translated by} \par
\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}
{\Large THE TRANSLATOR} \par
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\rule{0.9\txtwidth}{1pt} \par
\vspace{\baselineskip}
{\Large THE PUBLISHER}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\txtwidth}
{\color{Red}
\FSfont{5fh}% FontSite Fette Gotisch
\HUGE
\vspace{3.3\baselineskip}
H \\[1.15\baselineskip]
G \\[1.15\baselineskip]
P \\[1.15\baselineskip]
E
}\par
\vspace{4\baselineskip}
{\Large YEAR}
\end{minipage}
\endgroup}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\titleHGP
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where does one find said needed definitions? `titlepages.tex`?

Comment: yes. That is a normal tex document that you can compile.

Comment: How do I get more line spacing? The title is a bit longer and spans three lines, so it's all bunched up. I tried \linespread{2} but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This at least compiles. It does not quite look right, but it looks the same as when you compile `titlepages.tex` on a modern LaTeX and remember to redefine `\FSfont` as it is refering to commercial conts.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newlength{\tpheight}\setlength{\tpheight}{0.9\textheight}
\newlength{\txtheight}\setlength{\txtheight}{0.9\tpheight}
\newlength{\tpwidth}\setlength{\tpwidth}{0.9\textwidth}
\newlength{\txtwidth}\setlength{\txtwidth}{0.9\tpwidth}
\newlength{\drop}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{Red}{red}

\newcommand*{\FSfont}[1]{} 

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlingpage}

  \drop=0.1\txtheight
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.05\txtwidth}
    \color{Red}
    \rule{6pt}{\txtheight}
  \end{minipage}
  \hspace{0.05\txtwidth}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\txtwidth}
    \vspace*{\drop}
    {\Large THE AUTHOR} \\
    \rule{0.9\txtwidth}{1pt} \par
    \vspace{3\baselineskip}
    {\noindent\Huge\bfseries CONUNDRUMS} \par
    \vspace{2\baselineskip}
    {\Large\itshape A Handy Guide to Puzzles and Enigmas} \par
    \vspace{6.5\baselineskip}
    {\scshape after the foreign edition of year \\
      translated by} \par
    \vspace{0.1\baselineskip}
    {\Large THE TRANSLATOR} \par
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \rule{0.9\txtwidth}{1pt} \par
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    {\Large THE PUBLISHER}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\txtwidth}
    {\color{Red} 
      \FSfont{5fh}% FontSite Fette Gotisch
      \HUGE
      \vspace{3.3\baselineskip}
      H \\[1.15\baselineskip]
      G \\[1.15\baselineskip]
      P \\[1.15\baselineskip]
      E
    }\par
    \vspace{4\baselineskip}
    {\Large YEAR}
\end{minipage}
\end{titlingpage}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks impressive. I don't think I quite understood what the problem was, but I'll have a look at the code and compare with mine. Thanks very much!

Comment: (1) `titlepages` is not a LaTeX package, (2) you need extra code for that sniplet to work, (3) you probably need to figure out what your editor says when the compilation fails.

Comment: How do I get more line spacing? The title is a bit longer and spans three lines, so it's all bunched up. I tried \linespread{2} but that doesn't work.